# Automation Jira Ticketing

Tags: automation, jira, build-automation

I want to make project jira local ticketing as automation.
so if i want close the ticket, how to create automation with template?
because currently we do manual closing with fill rootcause, solution and comment..

Thankyou

can do automation closing jira ticket

Answer (score 0):

You can close ticket by using automation.
In automation, you should add a component "New action" and choose "Transition issue". In the "Destination status" field, you can choose the status that you want (example "Done").